# How far is it between Hobbiton and the Lonely Mountain?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, time

Although *The Hobbit* provides approximate times for the stages of Bilbo's and the dwarves' journey, it does not indicate how far they traveled. They left Hobbiton near the end of April and reached the Lonely Mountain around October, but they used various methods of transportation and were delayed multiple times, so it does not seem possible to estimate the distance from their travel time.

Therefore, is there an indication of how far the Lonely Mountain is from Hobbiton?

Comment: [14...err 12 weeks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kessel_Run).

Comment: There is in *The Lord of the Rings* (as the accepted answer states); but the geography of *The Hobbit* is less concrete, and one probably can't make a good estimate based purely on *The Hobbit*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Eowyn Challenge](http://home.insightbb.com/~eowynchallenge/Walk/walk.html)

THE HOBBIT:

397 miles: Travel with Bilbo from Bag End to Rivendell. [Work shown on worksheet here](http://home.insightbb.com/~eowynchallenge/Tools/Hobbit_BE_to_Rivendell/hobbit_be_to_rivendell.html)

570 Miles: Travel with Bilbo from Rivendell to Lonely Mountain. [Worksheet](http://home.insightbb.com/~eowynchallenge/Tools/Lonely_Mountain/lonely_mountain.html)

Total: 967 miles.

Their worksheets [are based on](http://home.insightbb.com/~eowynchallenge/Tools/tools.html):

> Our reference book is The Atlas of Middle-Earth- Karen W. Fonstad. Page 157 gives the date, hours traveled, mileage, where they ended, and even mph!! Mrs. Fonstad has graciously provided us with the most complete set of mileage charts in existence. She has journeyed to Rivendell following her own charts. You should also read the books as you journey to create vivid descriptions in your mind of the things you might see in Middle Earth as you journey.

Comment: Apropos nothing, the first I heard of that page was when reading this interesting blog: http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2012/07/23/walking/

Answer (score 3):

According to [LotR Project](http://lotrproject.com/timedistance/), Thorin & Co. traveled 950 miles. Those numbers are based on Karen Wynn Fonstad's *The Atlas of Middle-earth*.

Comment: Interesting. Both of our sources are based on the same primary source but come up with SLIGHTLY different numbers.

Comment: +1 because the web site you link to is uber-cool in its own right, independent of this question